# is there any what to implement a universal design for iphone and ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, layout

I am developing app for iphone and ipad but my biggest problem is to find any standard way of designing for both iphone and ipad and also for the future ios devices . is there any way or standard for it ?

I am already using Screen (height and Width) to set position and size of UI objects but most of times I should do a new design for ipad.

Comment: Universal binary seems the way to go, are you looking for something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `TopPaidApps` Sample project available on apple documentation.

Here are some link that will give you the glimpse on how to start the universal app project.

[link1](http://www.slideshare.net/cliffmcc/creating-a-universal-ios-application)

[link 2](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html)

[link 3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad)